# query a process by PID windows javascript

Tags: wsh, jscript

I have a few processes on windows and have there pid. It is RUNNING on the machine.

1. How can I query using js if the a process with the pid is up ?
2. Can I ensure in js that this the process (and not other process)

Comment: Are you talking about JavaScript running on the machine or in the browser? If the latter: It's unlikely that this is possible.

Comment: Is this from a browser environment? If so, does it need to be x-browsers, or just IE?

Comment: Yes sorry, it is running on the machine

Comment: How is it running on the machine? WSH? ASP?

Comment: java script and also vb and also wsh

Answer (score 1):

You can get a handle to a process by its ID using WMI:

```
var proc = GetObject("winmgmts:").Get("Win32_Process.Handle='" + pid + "'");
```

There are a few different properties you can access from the resulting object, such as `Caption` or `ExecutablePath`, to make sure it is the process you're looking for:

```
if (proc.ExecutablePath == "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe") {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript doesn't natively have access to the Operating System. However you may be able to access system calls from RingoJS or Node.js, if you're using Server Side JavaScript. Please provide more details about the environment you're using.

Comment: Sorry it is on machine and not from the browser.